# Is it possible to debug a query sooner?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Is there a way to look at the currently active requests (YSQL/YCQL) on a YugaByte node? I have noticed that some queries take a long time, and looking for ways to debug this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one of two ways:

- You can go to the RPCs in flight page and take a look at the currently running queries. This should give you an idea of which queries are slower. You can access this here:

  - YCQL: http://IP_ADDRESS:12000/rpcz
  - YSQL: http://IP_ADDRESS:13000/rpcz
- It is possible to enable slow query logging. I would join and ask in our Slack community chat to find out how to do this. This is something we should have documented, maybe you could contribute!